# Grant permission to execute procedure including all required other permissions

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions, sql-server-2012

I have a technical user, that has very limited permission on the database. I granted permission to one of the procedures, but this procedure uses a lot of other things (especially references other databases).

My procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.example AS BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM other_db.dbo.table
    SELECT * FROM yet_another_db.dbo.table
    INSERT INTO dbo.some_local_tables VALUES (1,2,3)
END
```

The user currently has not access to `other_db` and `yet_another_db`.

How can I grant permission to a stored procedure, including all permissions that are required to actually execute that procedure?

Comment: `with execute as owner`

Comment: @IvanStarostin will `with execute as owner` give additional permissions, like altering the procedure?

Comment: Elaborate what's happening within this SP in your question. And how is cross database access organized. To call other SPs, access tables - yes, this enough.

Comment: I don't see any `ALTER PROC` commands inside this proc. Why did you ask about it?

Comment: @IvanStarostin I want to grant permission to `execute` the procedure, if possible without granting any further permissions like altering or deleting the procedure, or any other permissions.

Comment: So give only this permission with `GRANT EXEC ON ... TO ...`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link with different scenarios of giving access to another database:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2549/options-for-cross-database-access-within-sql-server/

In short: you have to give access to this user or to follow cert-signing scenario (review another link in the end of that article.

Cert scenario will let you not to map current user to other database and not to give him explicitly any permissions to that database. But he'll be able to run this proc which accesses other databases.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.